# How do you select the 'maximum' struct from each group

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataFrame that contains an `id` column and a struct of two values `order_value`

```
example_input = spark.createDataFrame([(1, (1,2)), (1, (2,1)), (2, (1,2))], ["id", "order_value"])
```

I would like to keep one record from each `id`, that is the maximum of the `order_value` column. Specifically the maximum of the `order` (first part of order_value) with ties broken by the the maximum of the value (second part of order_value)

How can this be done?

`example_input.groupby('id').max()` doesn't seem to work as it complains that `order_value` is not numeric.

my desired output is given by:

```
example_output = spark.createDataFrame([(1, (2,1)), (2, (1,2))], ["id", "order_value"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [**`array_max`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/sql/#array_max) function in spark.

**`Example:`**

```
#groupby on id then collect_list to create an array to find max in the array

example_input.groupBy("id").agg(array_max(collect_list(col("order_value"))).alias("order_value")).\
show(10,False)
```